# Case when with condition loop

Tags: r, case, case-when

I'm new on R. I wrote a case when code but I want to parametizer because not always I have n = 5.
 is it possible?

```
iris 
iris$id_1 = sample(1:10)
iris$id_2 = sample(1:10)
iris$id_3 = sample(1:10)
iris$id_4 = sample(1:10)
iris$id_5 = sample(1:10)

x = 3

iris <- 
  iris %>%
  mutate(
    segmento = 
      case_when(
        id_5 >= x ~ 5,
        id_4 >= x ~ 4,
        id_3 >= x ~ 3,
        id_2 >= x ~ 2,
        id_1 >= x ~ 1,
      )
  )
```

The problem is I have not always 5 "id". Sometimes I have 3 and the code It will be:

```
  iris <- 
      iris %>%
      mutate(
        segmento = 
          case_when(
            id_3 >= x ~ 3,
            id_2 >= x ~ 2,
            id_1 >= x ~ 1,
          )
      )
```

Then I need to parametizer it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using multiple `case_when`,  based on the description, we can do (if we are comparing the number in the column name, extract that number with `sub`, do a comparison and get the column index with `max.col` on a logical matrix.  Here, we specify `last` so that if we have a row with `c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)`, it gives the column index as 4

```
nm1 <- grep("^id_\\d+", names(df), value = TRUE)
max.col(df[nm1] >= as.numeric(sub("id_", "", nm1))[col(df[nm1])], "last")
```

---

Based on the updated post with 'iris' example

```
nm1 <- grep("^id_\\d+", names(iris), value = TRUE)
max.col(iris[nm1] >= x, "last")
```

Comment: It's not max, It have a order. First priority is last (5) ...

Comment: but you dont use "x". X is value of refernce. If value of level last is greater than x then it will be last. If not it has to check  lower lever.